# Anchoring arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

The arrow from the circle around the checkmark to the 1 starts within the circle, not its border, and its arrowhead pierces the border of the target circle.  I would like, instead, for the arrow to run from circle to circle.

I suspect the problem is because the arrow and starting and ending at the borders of the underlying text object, not the circle I've drawn around them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{%
  square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum size=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm,
  arc/.style={->,> = latex'}
}

\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
        & $h_0$ & $h_1$ & $h_2$ \\
$t_0$   & & & \\
};

\node[circle] at (A-2-2) (a) {$\checkmark$};
\node[circle,fill=white] at ([xshift=0.3cm]A-2-3) (b) {$1$};
\draw[color=orange] (a) circle(0.4);
\draw[color=orange] (b) circle(0.4);
\draw[arc,color=orange,dashed] (a) to["{\textbf{\scriptsize WP1}}"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Not really clear

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

I only a little bit simplified your code -- use only one node for check mark and for number 1 in circle:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{%
  square matrix/.style={matrix of nodes,
                        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                        nodes in empty cells,
                        nodes = {draw, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0pt,
                                 anchor=center,
                                 align=center},
                        },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm,
  arc/.style={-latex'},  % <---
C/.style = {circle, draw=orange, text=black, 
            minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=0pt}, % <---
}

\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
        & $h_0$ & $h_1$ & $h_2$ \\
$t_0$   &       &       &       \\
};

\node (a) [C] at (A-2-2.center) {$\checkmark$}; % <---
\node (b) [C] at (A-2-3.center) {$1$};          
\path[arc,draw=orange,densely dashed] (a) to["\scriptsize {\textbf{WP1}}"] (b); % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you might looking for the following result:

[image]

For it you only need to move coordinates for circle placement. For example to:

```
\node (a) [C] at ([xshift=-3pt] A-2-2.center) {$\checkmark$};
\node (b) [C] at ([xshift= 3pt] A-2-3.center) {$1$};
```

Other code is the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understand the question correctly, but if I do, you want to synchronize the sizes of the circles without guessing hard-coded radii. This can be done with `eqparbox`, and one can make this a style, `equal size`. So if you want to have two nodes of the same sizes, just add `equal size` to the node options. If you want to have groups of nodes having the same sizes, use e.g. `equal size=A` for the first group, `equal size=B` for the next group, and so on.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{%
  square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum size=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm,
  arc/.style={->,> = latex'},
  equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end
    node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},equal size/.default=A
}

\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
        & $h_0$ & $h_1$ & $h_2$ \\
$t_0$   & & & \\
};

\node[circle,draw=orange,equal size,inner sep=1pt] at (A-2-2) (a) {$\checkmark$};
\node[circle,draw=orange,equal size,inner sep=1pt] at ([xshift=0.3cm]A-2-3) (b) {$1$};
\draw[arc,color=orange,dashed] (a) to["WP1" font=\bfseries\scriptsize] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]