# Making a simple legend on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing a document that requires very few actual plots and I'm happy with the aesthetic of tikz. However, I'm having trouble finding a way to make a simple legend on tikz. I know there's a way with the data visualization library, but it seems far too convoluted for simple graphs. Some people suggested using matrices, which turned out to be pretty much what I wanted, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (8,0)  node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2)  node[above]{$y$};
\draw[green,samples=100,domain=-1:8] plot(\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
\draw[red,samples=100,domain=-1:8] plot(\x,{cos(deg(\x))});
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(pi/2,1)--(3*pi/2,-1)--(5*pi/2,1);
\matrix [draw, above left] at (8,-2) {
  \node[green,font=\tiny] {$\sin x$}; \\
  \node[red,font=\tiny] {$\cos x$}; \\
  \node[blue,font=\tiny] {Lines}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I want the legend to show the draw style of the graphs. Like what we can see on the tikz manual:

[image]

Can I do that with matrices? I would also want the legend to be aligned to the left, right now it's to the right, but no idea how to change it.

Comment: Use `PGFPlots` (it is build on top of TikZ) - it will do it automatically.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also prefer pfgplots but for completeness here is a method using `pic`s.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/legend entry/.style={code={%   
        \draw[pic actions] 
        (-0.5,0.25) sin (-0.25,0.4) cos (0,0.25) sin (0.25,0.1) cos (0.5,0.25);}}]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (8,0)  node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2)  node[above]{$y$};
\draw[green!70!black,samples=100,domain=-1:8] plot(\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
\draw[red,samples=100,domain=-1:8] plot(\x,{cos(deg(\x))});
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(pi/2,1)--(3*pi/2,-1)--(5*pi/2,1);
\matrix [draw, above left] at (8,-2) {
 \pic[green!70!black]{legend entry}; &  \node[green!70!black,font=\tiny] {$\sin x$}; \\
 \pic[red]{legend entry}; &  \node[red,font=\tiny] {$\cos x$}; \\
 \pic[blue]{legend entry}; &  \node[blue,font=\tiny] {Lines}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To align the text nodes you can use [these tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512761/227987).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{lequal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][l]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    lequal size/.default=A,}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/legend entry/.style={code={%   
        \draw[pic actions] 
        (-0.5,0.25) sin (-0.25,0.4) cos (0,0.25) sin (0.25,0.1) cos (0.5,0.25);}}]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (8,0)  node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2)  node[above]{$y$};
\draw[green!70!black,samples=100,domain=-1:8] plot(\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
\draw[red,samples=100,domain=-1:8] plot(\x,{cos(deg(\x))});
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(pi/2,1)--(3*pi/2,-1)--(5*pi/2,1);
\matrix [draw, above left] at (8,-2) {
 \pic[green!70!black]{legend entry}; &  \node[lequal size,green!70!black,font=\tiny] {$\sin x$}; \\
 \pic[red]{legend entry}; &  \node[lequal size,red,font=\tiny] {$\cos x$}; \\
 \pic[blue]{legend entry}; &  \node[lequal size,blue,font=\tiny] {Lines}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You guys are right, I should probably learn to use pgfplots, but this will do the trick for now.

Comment: This is still aligned to the right though. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: @Nickesponja What is aligned to the right?

Comment: I mean that the text on the legend entries, "sin x", "cos x", "Lines" is aligned to the right. I'd prefer it aligned to the left, that is, each line of text starting just after the corresponding pic

Comment: @Nickesponja They are centered, I added a way to align them left. The alignment is controlled by `l` in `\eqmakebox[#1][l]{`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's perfect

Answer (score 3):

To get a consistent look, I suggest to never use pure TikZ for plots, but PGFPlot that is build on top of TikZ.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  samples=100,
  domain=-1:8,
  xmin=-1, xmax=8,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  axis lines=middle,
  ticks=none,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  legend pos=south east,
  width=\textwidth,
  height=0.5*\textwidth]
\addplot[green] {sin(deg(\x))};
\addplot[red] {cos(deg(\x))};
\addplot[blue] coordinates{(0,0) (pi/2,1) (3*pi/2,-1) (5*pi/2,1)};
\addlegendentry{$sin(x)$}
\addlegendentry{$cos(x)$}
\addlegendentry{Lines}
\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with legend]