# How can I make my tikz matrix look more like an array?

Tags: tikz-matrix

Consider the following two matrices:

[image]

The matrix on the left is rendered with the code

```
\left[
  \begin{array}{rrrr}
    1  & -32  & 0  & 15 \\
    16 & -138 & -3 & 5  \\
    4  & 14   & 11 & 19
  \end{array}
\right]
```

The one on the left is given by:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[
  , matrix of math nodes
  , left delimiter = {[}
  , right delimiter = {]}
  ] (m)
  {
    1  & -32  & 0  & 15 \\
    16 & -138 & -3 & 5  \\
    4  & 14   & 11 & 19 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want the one on the right to look like the one on the left. A few obvious differences are:

1. The columns of the matrix on the left are right-aligned.
2. The whitespace is distributed differently in the two matrices.

What can I do to make the matrix on the right look more like the matrix on the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use `eqparbox` to make the nodes equally wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512761/228539), and align the contents right, say. The rest can be done by changing some keys. If you have not already done so, have a look at the `nicematrix` package which offers a number of nice and well documented options.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{r/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup$},
    execute at end node={$\egroup\eqmakebox[#1-\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][r]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    r/.default=R}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,cells={nodes={r,inner sep=2pt}},
  inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,%<- controls the distance and height of the delimiters
  column sep=1.5pt,
  left delimiter = {[},right delimiter = {]}] (m)
  {
    1  & -32  & 0  & 15 \\
    16 & -138 & -3 & 5  \\
    4  & 14   & 11 & 19 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]